# Bootstrap DateTimePicker v4 not working on my ASP.NET page

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, bootstrap-4

I'm following [this](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Installing/#nuget) guide, but I am still getting a failure.
I did execute

```
PM> Install-Package Bootstrap.v3.Datetimepicker
PM> Install-Package Bootstrap.v3.Datetimepicker.CSS
```

And this is the header of the page:

```
   <script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/moment.min.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/bootstrap-datetimepicker.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" href="/Content/bootstrap-datetimepicker-build.less" />
    <!-- or -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/Content/bootstrap-datetimepicker.css" />
     <!--End of Datetimepicker-->
    <link href="Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datatables/1.10.12/css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

Note: I made a little modifications because it was causing a 404 finding the files, for instance I changed `jquery.min.js` with `jquery-3.3.1.min.js` and `/scripts/bootstrap-datetimepicker.*js"` with `/scripts/bootstrap-datetimepicker.js"`.

Then I added [this](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/#minimum-setup) code as follows:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class='col-sm-6'>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker2'>
                <input type='text' class="form-control" />
                <span class="input-group-addon">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
            });
        });
    </script>
</div>
```

But I am getting this error:

[image]
At this line:  `$('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({`

I searched a lot and found lots of answers which are not working to me.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: can you try to see if `'datetimepicker` was loaded correctly in the browser by going to sources

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I fixed it. The problem was, on the page was also a bootstrap table wich required this script:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Apparently, It was overriding the previous import. Deleting it fixed it.